# Command line to change file extension of all files under a folders and its subfolders

Tags: cmd

I am looking for a command line which can change the file extension of all the files that are under a folder and its subfolders.  Is there any way to do this?

I tried with `ren *.js *.txt` but this only changes the file extension of the files under one folder.

Comment: Do you really mean ms-dos? Or are you using the command prompt on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by ms-dos you really mean the command prompt on Windows. Not many people still use ms-dos.

The following will run your REN command on each folder within the hierarchy that contains .js files. It is probably a bit more efficient then running REN for each file individually.

```
for /r %F in (.) do @if exist "%F\*.js" ren "%F\*.js" "*.txt"
```

Double up the percents (`%F` becomes `%%F`) if run within a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
For /R %G in (*.js) do REN "%G" "%~nG.txt"
```

Note that you'll need to use `%%` instead of `%` if running from a batch file.